# Css table gutter inner only

Tags: css

I try to make a table with space between cell but without outside space for cells at border, i made a simply code to show my problem:

```css
html, body, div,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}


.whatiwant {
  width: 80px;
  height: 110px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position:absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
td{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="whatiwant"></div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want a table like the blue border, anyone know how to make it with css only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this :

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  margin: -10px;
}
td{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `border-bottom` and `border-right` and exclude specific `td` using last child:

```css
html,
body,
div,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


table {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 1px;
  border-right: solid 10px #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 10px #fff;
}
td:last-child {
  border-right: solid 0px #fff;
}
tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: solid 0px #fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work on IE8, probably because of last-child 's not supported

Comment: To be honest I never have IE8 in my mind when implement something.